# Is there a way to generate the post URL in the GET action if both the GET and the POST methods share the same name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to generate the post URL in the GET action if both the GET and the POST methods share the same name?

The reason for needing to generate the post URL in the controller is that we aren't dealing with the views but only providing the ViewModel that contains a payload in the form of JSON. And the front-end needs to know where to post form values to.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MethodName(string id)
{
...
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MethodName(ViewModel model)
{
...
}
```

e.g. the get URL would be:

> /controller/methodname/123

and the post URL would be:

> /controller/methodname

in the get action, I need to feed the front-end with the post URL of which the form values would be consumed.

using `Url.Action("methodname", "controller", new { id = string.Empty})` would generate a URL that's the same to the post URL, but it's sort of hack-ish way

Another option would be to define a route for the post method and use `Url.RouteUrl("PostMethodName")` to generate the URL.

Neither of these seem ideal, so is there another (cleaner) way to get this done?

Comment: Does `Url.Action("MethodName", "controller")` not work?

Comment: not really, because it would generate the url with the id that's passed in in the get action, the url would be /controller/methodname/123

Comment: Ah right, I had forgotten about that. Those are indeed the two out-of-the-box methods I know of that you can use. A third one is implementing a custom Route class, I'll post some code in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Walter,

I am failing to understand how this is "hack-ish." You are providing a restricted post action with a strongly typed model, the only difference if your action result type. The URL's can be the same if you wish.

Alternativtly you can create just an action for your aJax method such as.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ajaxMethod(ViewModel model){
  //...
}
```

This is restrictive to just the `HttpPost` method and contains your view model. Actions dont need views they simply return an action result. If you wanted to get very bare-bones and action can be an `object` returning anything. Your route for this action is similar to all other routes:

```
@Url.Action("ajaxMethod", "controller")
```

to generate

```
/controller/ajaxMethod
```

I may have completly missed the question, please let me know if this doesnt help.

EDIT: Updated from comments.

Just to add if you would like to generate a route or action url in your controller action you can simply use the Url helper in your action such as.

`ViewBag.Url = Url.Action("MethodName", "Controller");`

Comment: maybe my question should have been "is there a way to generate the post url in the get action if both get and post methods share the same name"

the goal is, in the get action, I need to tell the front-end what the post url is. but because the method names are the same so in the get action, it always generates an url with the id that's passed in.

Comment: By front end I am assuming you mean view. So you want to generate a route Url from your action to pass to your view? How would this URL differ from the Url the view Generates using the view helpers? I would go with your initial idea of just using `Url.Action("methodname", "controller")` as that isnt hackish at all. Cheers.

Comment: then it would bring the id that's passed in in the get action, so the url would be /controller/methodname/id. it's not the post url I want it to be. in the view, I could use @using(Html.BeginForm("methodname", "controller")) to achieve that, but unfortunately I'm unable to do anything in the view but only to provide the urls that the view would use. I hope this explains what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope this helps? Just added how you can generate a URL string from your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a custom `Route` implementation. A very basic one that includes a line to fix your problem (*Drop the existing route parameters*) can look like this:

```
public class CustomRoute : Route
{
    public CustomRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, routeHandler)
    {
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (routeData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        /* custom implementation here */

        return routeData;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        /*
         * GetVirtualPath is called until a suitable route is found.
         * This means modifying the passed RouteValueDictionary has consequenses for subsequent calls.
         * Therefore, always work with a copy if you want to modify any values: new RouteValueDictionary(values)
         */

        /*
         * Drop the existing route parameters. Implicitness can only cause confusion.
         */
        requestContext = new RequestContext(requestContext.HttpContext, new RouteData());

        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    }
}
```

You probably also want to have `MapRoute` methods for your custom route. For this, you just need to look at the [original implementation](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteCollectionExtensions.cs), copy paste it and replace `Route` with `CustomRoute`.